# finding a function with given boundary conditions

Tags: calculus, functions

$f(x)$ is given in the interval (a,b) with following properties,

$$f(a) = 0 \hspace{1cm} f'(a) = 0 \hspace{1cm} f''(a) = 0 \\f(b) = 1 \hspace{1cm} f'(b) = 0 \hspace{1cm} f''(b) = 0  $$

I need to prove that $f'(\xi) = 0$ for some $\xi \in (a,b)$ or give a counter example function.

From the given information I can deduce that, 
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(b) = 0 \hspace{.5cm} f'(a) = 0 \implies f''(\zeta) = 0 \hspace{.5cm} \zeta \in (a,b) \\
f''(b) = 0 \hspace{.5cm} f''(a) = 0 \hspace{.5cm} f''(\zeta) =0 \hspace{.5cm} \implies f'''(\eta_1) = 0 , \eta_1 \in (a, \zeta) \hspace{.5cm} f'''(\eta_2) = 0 , \eta_2 \in ( \zeta, b) \\
f'''(\eta_2) = 0 \hspace{.5cm} f'''(\eta_2) = 0 \implies f''''(\mu) = 0
\end{eqnarray}

But I am not able to draw any conclusions about first derivative of the function. Is is possible to prove that  $f'(\xi) = 0$ for some $\xi \in (a,b)$ or give a counter example? Please also see if tags are appropriate.

Comment: Try to find a simple function (Polynomial), which satisfies the conditions and has $f'(x) > 0\qquad \forall x\in(a,b)$

Comment: Why not try to make a simple graph of the function in the first place? And does the interval for $\xi$ _include_ the end-points $a$ and $b$ ?